# Accessing a list through a name stored in a variable

Tags: python, list

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"] 
curfile = "thislist" 
print(curfile[0]) #should give apple
```

I have presented a rough idea about what I am trying to do, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: **Don't do this.** *You don't need to do this.*

Comment: You can replace the second line with `curfile = thislist` without the quotation marks that should work.

Comment: I actually get the variable as a result of a function